# Mass email from contacts related to custom object

Tags: email, custom-field, object

We have an object in our salesforce instance called conference data and in that object there is data of all the contacts that have registered for our 2016 event. 
 
When i go Contact > Mass Email it only allows me to send emails somehow related to the account or contact. The field in the Conference data that gets contact info is a look up field not master detail.

Comment: Can you explain your problem briefly..@Greg

Comment: Im trying to send a mass email to people from a custom object  called conference data.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a custom button in that custom object.And iterate all contacts and put emails in a list.And sent email at once@Greg